# botton up algorithm for fibonacci sequence

Tags: python, dynamic

The exception:

```
C:\Users\Wandres\venv\insertionsort\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Wandres/PycharmProjects/insertionsort/fibobottomup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Wandres\PycharmProjects\insertionsort\fibobottomup.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(fibbottonup(5))
  File "C:\Users\Wandres\PycharmProjects\insertionsort\fibobottomup.py", line 8, in fibbottonup
    f=fib[k-1]+fib[k-2]
KeyError: 0
```

And the code

```py
def fibbottonup (n):  
    fib = {}     
    for  k in range (1, n + 1):    
        if k<2:       
           f=1            
           fib[k]=f        
        else:             
           f=fib[k-1] + fib[k-2]            
           fib[k]=f     
    return fib[n]
```

I am learning about dynamic programming so i tried to use the theory and i want to add every element of the fibonacci sequence in the array "fib". I do not know where the mistake is.

Comment: Is my first question, i thought that it was similar with mathexhange so i edit my post again, sorry by the trouble in my first post. Thank you

Comment: Explain more like did you get any error.

Comment: When i put print(fibbottonup(5)) for example appear: C:\Users\Wandres\venv\insertionsort\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Wandres/PycharmProjects/insertionsort/fibobottomup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Wandres\PycharmProjects\insertionsort\fibobottomup.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(fibbottonup(5))
  File "C:\Users\Wandres\PycharmProjects\insertionsort\fibobottomup.py", line 8, in fibbottonup
    f=fib[k-1]+fib[k-2]
KeyError: 0

Comment: Show errors and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: Just think what the code in the for-loop does for `k = 2`.

Comment: Show it as properly formatted text in the question, not as image.

Comment: thanks anybody, i appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def fibbottonup (n):  
    fib = [0, 1]   
    for i in range (n-1):    
        fib.append(fib[i] + fib[i+1])
    return fib[n]
```

It is the code and
Explanation is:
First two items of ibonacci sequence is them
0,
1
After that it starts to sum before two elements to find current element for all elements. So I did it.

Comment: thank you, terrific, i used {} to store de sequence, and you use append wow i like that. In my code i did j in range(0, n+1) and it works too. Thank you again

Comment: `range(n-1)` would suffice; since `fib[0]` and `fib[1]` are predefined, each iteration of the loop defines `fib[i+2]`. So when `i = n-2`, you'll define `fib[n]`, which you'll return.

Comment: {} defines dictionary in python and array is better for this.

Comment: Firstly range(0, n+1) and range(n+1) is same, secondly dont use range(n+1) becouse already you'll use fib[n] why you calculating fib[n+2] ? (So use range(n-1))

Comment: Thank you @0x01010, in facto i put yesterday, range(0,n) because the comments. Now i am reading your comment, i am processing. How is that, don´t use range? Thank you

Comment: @0x01010, Why is better to use array in place to {}? Thanks a lot, i am beginner in all this, python, programming. Sorry

Comment: Becouse dictionary storages two arrays: keys and values. But you can do this with one array. It is more simple to process and smaller (on RAM)

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that for k=2 the code accesses `fib[k-2]` = `fib[0]` but the key 0 was never added to `fib`.

Comment: thank you so much, but how i improve that?

Comment: i put range(0,n+1), it works, thank you